# How to remove invalid date values in MariaDB 10.1?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have one table with one datecolumn

**foo (before):**

```
+------------+
| datecolumn |
+------------+
| 1939-04-06 |
| 1949-02-30 |
+------------+
```

I want to set the dates to NULL if they are invalid.

**foo (after):**

```
+------------+
| datecolumn |
+------------+
| 1939-04-06 |
| NULL       |
+------------+
```

In MySQL (5.7) I could just use this trick in order to accomplish just that:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` MODIFY COLUMN `datecolumn` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL FIRST;
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
ALTER TABLE `foo` MODIFY COLUMN `datecolumn` date NULL DEFAULT NULL FIRST;
SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
UPDATE `foo` SET `datecolumn` = NULL WHERE `datecolumn` = '0000-00-00';
```

However, this does not seem to work in MariaDB 10.1, regardless of what I tried:

1) various SQL_MODE's

2) various STR_TO_DATE or DATE_FORMAT approaches (I hoped to get NULL I converted the invalid date-string to a date)

Could anybody help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: So are you saying that `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1949-02-30','%Y,%m,%d')` does _not_ return `NULL` in MariaDB?  Then what does it actually return?

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1949-02-30','%Y,%m,%d')` does return `NULL` but so does `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1949-02-10','%Y,%m,%d')`. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1949-02-30','%Y-%m-%d')` however returns `1949-02-30` (analogue for 1949-02-10).

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` not returning `NULL` appears to be a bug. It exists in MySQL 5.5/5.6 and in all versions of MariaDB. In MySQL 5.7 it seems to fixed, not perfectly since it produces duplicate warnings, but at least it does return `NULL`; should be fixed soon in MariaDB as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE foo SET datecolumn = CAST(datecolumn AS DATE);
```

Make sure that strict mode is unset in SQL_MODE, otherwise any attempt will cause an error.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Modifying the datecolum to a datetime type DID set it to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Maybe the STR_TO_DATE problem you mentioned above indeed is a bug, but your solution works just fine for now.